# When did the Soul Eater anime and manga diverge?

Tags: soul-eater

From what I've heard, the anime version of Soul Eater was fairly faithful to the manga up to a certain point (excluding a few fillers). However, the ending of the anime was nothing like the manga (which is still ongoing), and in my view the end of the anime was its weakest point. I want to start reading the manga at the point where the two diverged.

What is the last manga chapter that was adapted in the anime, and what episode does that correspond to? Also, are there any chapters before that which I would have missed from the anime (especially those which have important plot points)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it would be the safest bet to start reading once they introduced the Spider Witch. It's when their paths started to separate more and more. That is on **chapter 23th, Daily Life**.

You will notice quite a lot similarities from the anime, but that's where they start to go different ways.