# Why was the Soul Eater anime different than the manga?

Tags: soul-eater

The anime is missing severals arcs, like Noah's or one about Witches. Is there a reason behind those differences or is it just that the manga wasn't over yet ?

Comment: [Related](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/when-did-the-soul-eater-anime-and-manga-diverge)

Comment: i've seen both so i know when the divergences start but i'm asking 'why'

Comment: That's why I said "Related" and not "Duplicate" ;)

Comment: it could much like the fma series ? sounds an awful similar to that case , just that the remaining manga wasn't adapted into a new anime series again

Comment: yeah i guess it is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because the anime had caught up with the manga and the producers wanted to continue rather than wait for the rest of the story.

Comment: Please add a reference to your answer :)

Comment: The manga ended in 2013 and the anime ended in 2009, is not that enough?

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt While your answer sounds legit in itself, we seek documented answers with credible sources. Where did you find out that the anime has caught up with the manga? Has there been any official declaration that they wanted to continue rather than wait?